# How to refresh a view in main activity from an adapter?

Tags: android, android-activity, view, refresh, adapter

I have a graph in main activity also I have a recycler view in main activity. Custom adapter is used for recyclerview. I have a check box and swipe layout in list item layout. in swipe layout there is a delete button.

I want to reset the graph of main activity when I check the check box or when I delete any item.

For this I created one method in main activity. And called this method in adapter onCheckedChangeListener and on click of delete.

But I am getting a null pointer exception on mBarChart. i.e . graph. I have instantiated in mBarChart in setUI method and this is called in onCreate of an activity.

resetMethod

```
    public void resetGraph(Context context)
{

    mBarChart.invalidate();

}
```

in adapter :

```
  Context conext;
  MainActivity mainActivity;

  mainActivity = new MainActivity();

  mainActivity.resetGraph(conext);
```

How to do this? Please help.. Thank you..

Comment: What about `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: how and where should I call? @Clairvoyant

Comment: you want to refresh data of adapter ?

Comment: I want to refresh data of a bar chart. @NarenderNishad

Comment: simple use notifiydatasetchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Adapter call your resetMethod this way

```
((MainActivity)context).resetGraph(context);
```

Comment: That gives me a Class Cast Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Create a interface that implement Activity, Main activity in your case and override method and perform operation.

```
//Interface

public interface OnRefreshViewListner{

  public void refreshView();

}


//Main Activity
 MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRefreshViewListner
{

  //Other methods

  @Override
  public void refreshView(){

    // write refresh code here

 }

}


//Initialize Interface in adapter constructor

public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private OnRefreshViewListner mRefreshListner;
 public YourAdapter (Context context) {
       mRefreshListner = (OnRefreshViewListner)context; 
    }

    //call MainActivity method
    mRefreshListner.refreshView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter, you should not create a new instance of MainActivity and call resetGraph(). You should use the instance of MainActivity, that created the adapter. Send the instance of MainActivity to the adapter, `new Adapter(this)` and save it in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a view from the context of an adapter like this :
cast context to activity.
use findviewbyid method to find the view you want.
initiliaze it to a variable.

```
View v = ((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(WHATEVER_VIEW_COMPONENT_YOU_WANT);
```

change the variable as you want.
note. Don't forget to use the type of view that you want and cast the findview method to it.

If you want to call a method just cast the context to MainActivity and call it.