# Why cant I call a method from adapter?

Tags: android

I have an adapter class and an activity, I want to call the activity method from adapter

> Adapter

```
holder.fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((MainActivity)context).getTotalPrice();

                }
            });
```

> MainActivity

```
@Override
public void getTotalPrice() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Message Has Been Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I want to call getTotalPrice method form adapter

Comment: This is not possible, you can't call methods like this between acticity and fragment

Comment: You can use interface as a callback to the activity

Comment: Use interface approch to call methods in activity [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982209/how-to-refresh-a-view-in-main-activity-from-an-adapter/36982464#36982464)

Comment: Because you are using the wrong approach

Comment: Why don't you simply pass your "totalPrice" in the adapter constructor as you pass the context?

Comment: Why there is @Override above getTotalPrice()?

Comment: Otherwise the approach you are using is absolute right. We can call activity method from adapter if we have context of that activity in  adapter by type casting as you done

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
holder.fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          onClicked.getTotalPrice("Price");   
     }                
});
```

Your interface in adapter class:

```
 public interface OnClicked {
        void getTotalPrice(String price);
    }
```

At the top of your adapter class:

```
 private OnClicked onClicked;
```

and initialize it in adapter's constructor like:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, ...) {
   onClicked = (OnClicked) context;
}
```

Now make your activity implement the interface like:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyAdapter.OnClicked{
...

@Override
public void getTotalPrice(String price) {
    //do whatever you like here
    }
}
```

Now its done!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for how to write an interface here is what you can do :)

Declare interface in your adapter,

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public interface ClickInformerInterface{
            public void getTotalPrice();
        }
```

Declare a property in YourAdapter to hold the reference to class which confirms the interface :)

```
ClickInformerInterface mInterface;
```

and in your onclick listener call this :)

```
holder.fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        mInterface.getTotalPrice();

                }
            });
```

In your main activity :) after creating an adapter instance set `this` as adapter's interface :)

```
YourAdapter youradapter = new YourAdapter(....)
youradapter.mInterface = this;
```

Confirm ClickInformerInterface in your mainActivity using,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements YourAdapter. ClickInformerInterface{
```

and finally implement method getTotalPrice() in MainActivity :)

```
public void getTotalPrice() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Message Has Been Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method directly in you adapter class. as like below.

> Adapter

```
holder.fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    getTotalPrice(context);

            }
        });
```

> Method in adapter class means same class

```
 public void getTotalPrice(Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Your Message Has Been Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: That's only valid if adapter is inner, non-static class.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call activity methods from adapter directly. There are several ways to do what you want. Two most popular ways are Interface and EventBus.

I recommend using EventBus, since it's much easier to implement, and requires less code.

In your Activity, create a method that reacts to specific event:

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(MyButtonClickEvent e){
    //do stuff
}
```

In your adapter, send such event:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyButtonClickEvent());
```

Don't forget to register for events in your activity:

```
onStart/onStop: EventBus.getDefault().register(this)/unregister(this);
```

For more information, visit EventBus github page: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

You can send broadcast from Adapter and can receive broadcast in Main Activity.