# Return result from custom dialog to activity

Tags: android, dialog

I have an Activity.
In that Activity i have one Custom Dialog.In that dialog one button is there.on click of that button i want to change the color of a text which i have in my activity.how to acheive that.
    can anyone please help me.
    My code ---

```
public class Test extends Activity{
TextView tv;
Button b;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.test);
         tv = (TextView)tv.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
         button initialization code..
        b.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            popup();

          }
    }
            public void popup(final int position)
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Test.this);
        TextView view
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);

        view = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.view1);
        view .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
      toast msg...
              }

        });
}
```

Comment: `popup ` method is in same class in which want to change color of text? then `tv ` inside onClick method

Comment: Use listeners to send callback from dialog to activity [you can check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982209/how-to-refresh-a-view-in-main-activity-from-an-adapter/36982464#36982464)

Comment: yes popup method is in same class

Comment: how you call popup() without any arguments? your method shows one integer parameter

Comment: @ananya change color in popup's onclick method, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void popup() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);

    dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // remove dialog
            dialog.dismiss();

            // change color of text
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.change_my_color)).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

    });

    dialog.show();
}
```